# sp2013: Cannot find document template option in my document library, why?

Tags: template

I am using sp2013. I have created a new custom document library. I went to the listsettings -> advanced settings. I was especting here an option to edit or set another document template. But I dont see the option document template. Do I miss some feature?

Answer (score 0):

`Document Template` management depends whether `Content Types` management is enabled or not.
In case when management of content types is enabled, Document Template should be managed via Content Types.